# Recolor a given DrawingImage in WPF (in code)

Tags: wpf, colors, drawing

I have a DrawingImage which I have converted from SVG by the magnificent [Svg2Xaml plugin](http://svg2xaml.codeplex.com). This way I can let the users easily define the visuals of some elements in my application.

There are some use-cases where I would like to recolor the given DrawingImage. The simplest case would be to make it grayscale.

Is there a way to recursively go through all the elements, get their color and switch it to their grayscale counterparts? Or - for example - use something like a "filter" on the whole image?

I'm not really experienced in WPF, but if this could be done it would make my work a lot easier.

What would be my best choice?

Also it is important that the DrawingImage uses vector graphics, so I wouldn't want to pixellate the image.

Comment: for the specific case of making a Visual grayscale, you may want to take a look at the [Shader Effect Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @HighCore thanks. It seems it suits my needs, I'm going to test it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer:

for the specific case of making a Visual grayscale, you may want to take a look at the [Shader Effect Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Is there a way to rebuild the WPF projects in VS2012? There is no guide for it in on the codeplex page and I'm starting to become quite confused over it.

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure how to do what I want in code. Can you mock something minimal up?

Answer (score 1):

U might need to look at the WPF **resource dictionary**, and use **DynamicResource**

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="FrontColor">White</Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground" Color="{DynamicResource FrontColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Sorry if the question was not descriptive enough. The DrawingImage has no ResourceDictionaries, since it's created by the linked library. Also I don't want it to change colors on the fly, just directly after I loaded it, so a DynamicResource might be an overshoot, as the DrawingImage is not even visible then. Correct me if I'm wrong.